# Parsing Savon XML Response

Tags: ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails-4, savon

Here is the response from a SOAP request in SOAPUI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <PostApplication_V5Response xmlns="http://QuiddiServicePricePoints.org/">
     <PostApplication_V5Result><![CDATA[<QuiddiSerivce>
        <Application>
           <Status>PURCHASED</Status>
           <RedirectURL>http://www.google.com?test=abc&xyz=123</RedirectURL>
        </Application>
     </QuiddiSerivce>]]></PostApplication_V5Result>
  </PostApplication_V5Response>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However when I get the `response.body` from the Savon request it returns

```
{:post_application_v5_response=>{:post_application_v5_result=>"<QuiddiSerivce><Application><Status>PURCHASED</Status><RedirectURL>http://www.google.com?test=abc&xyz=123</RedirectURL></Application></QuiddiSerivce>", :@xmlns=>"http://QuiddiServicePricePoints.org/"}}
```

As you can see, the data I need, namely Status and RedirectURL, our still in XML format.

I've tried to convert `[:post_application_v5_response][:post_application_v5_result]` to a Hash using `Hash.from_xml()`, but it fails due to illegal characters in the RedirectURL.

How can I correctly escape characters in the RedirectURL so that I can convert the result to a hash, or otherwise access the Status and RedirectURL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse response body. And then search parsed document for desired values.

```
require 'nokogiri'
response_body = {:post_application_v5_response=>{:post_application_v5_result=>"<QuiddiSerivce><Application><Status>PURCHASED</Status><RedirectURL>http://www.google.com?test=abc&xyz=123</RedirectURL></Application></QuiddiSerivce>", :@xmlns=>"http://QuiddiServicePricePoints.org/"}}
res = Nokogiri.XML(response_body[:post_application_v5_response][:post_application_v5_result])
p res.search('Status').text
p res.search("RedirectURL").text
```

The result is:

```
#=> "PURCHASED"
#=> "http://www.google.com?test=abc=123"
```

Comment: Looks like an overkill for me. `res.scan(/<Status>(.*)<\/Status>/)[0][0]` will do the trick w/out `nokogiri` dependency.

Comment: There’s More Than One Way To Do It (c)